# Linux Terminal : Process that ends with a specific name

Tags: linux, terminal

My question is :
How do I find all the running processes that end with "sh".
I know that "ps aux" lists all the processes that are running and also "grep" prints a specific named process which is written inside " ".
I know I have to combine the command "ps aux" and also "grep" with a wildcard.

My solution is ps aux | grep "*sh" but it does not run properly.
How could it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: ps aux | grep "sh$"

The "$" sign is regular expression that is used for pattern match at the end of the line. In this case, the pattern is "sh" so we used "sh$"

Comment: This fits just fine for my issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to use `pgrep` command. See [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep).

```
pgrep -f "sh$"
```

Will return list of `pid`s

```
pgrep -af "sh$"
```

Will return list of `pid`s and `command`s

Comment: This works fine for my issue but I think I need a simplier answer for that issue. Although, Im really thankful you offered me a solution!